# how to control the size of the collection view cell layout swift storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I'm a beginner don't mind my coding nor my english I hope you can help me with this problem that you even might find it silly.
I have been facing a problem with resizing the cell.
I saw a few youtube tutorials and still couldn't find how to solve it!!

[I changed the sizes here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltUyw.png)

[I also tried and changed it in the cell (the book picture is actually a button)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuGPj.png)

[and here is the output.  so how can I resize it? I want it to be 2 columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUhc7.png)

here is the code

```
class resViewViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource
    {
            func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
                return CGSize(width: 140, height: 180)
            }


        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return resourcesName.count
        }

     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

            let cell = collection.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! resourceCellCollectionViewCell
            cell.name.text = resourcesName[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }
```

[the new output after fixing the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDwbT.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the class you are looking for is the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`.  Your `UICollectionView` has a delegate and the delegate can implement the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol.  Inside that implementation you can specify the size of the cells by implementing

```
collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)
```

So I would expect your code above to read:

```
class resViewViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource
{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 140, height: 180)
    }
```

Note that the class is implements the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol instead of just `UICollectionViewDelegate`

Then, in your Layout, you need to set the autoresizing mask of the view contained in the cell so that it shrinks or grows with the cell itself

[image: Change Autoresize mask settings]

Comment: thank you for answering.. but i have tried it and it didn't work :( maybe i put it wrong can you check the code please ....

Comment: thank you for editing the codes' format I'm new at this website.... so do you have any other solution in mind?

Comment: I added a clarifying code segment to my answer.  If the problem is still there I may need to write a longer sample.

Comment: it solved half the problem :) as in photo 3 the pictures were next to each other (4 columns) and now it is 2 columns like i wanted. but, the button is still small and i cant see the label below the button .... so my guess the distribution of the cells worked but not actually the things inside the cell ... i added anther picture.. thank you

Comment: You probably need to tell the system to grow or shrink the content of the cell with the cell itself.  I attached a picture of my own.

Comment: It worked !!!!! Thank you so much really i've been looking for a solution to this problem all day!!!!